# Django with PIL - '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to resize an uploaded photo before saving.  Note that I'm using formsets to upload the pictures.  I'm using BytesIO to open the file.  At the last step, I get the error - `'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name'`.  Why is this?

```
def fsbo_create_listing(request):
    PhotoFormSet = formset_factory(OwnerListingPhotoForm, extra=15)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OwnerListingForm(request.POST)
        photo_formset = PhotoFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and photo_formset.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            for i in photo_formset:
                if i.instance.pk and i.instance.photo == '':
                    i.instance.delete()
                elif i.cleaned_data:
                    temp = i.save(commit=False)
                    temp.listing = form.instance
                    temp.save() # Where the error happens
```

---

```
def clean_photo(self):
    picture = self.cleaned_data.get('photo')
    # I had to import ImageFieldFile.  If picture is already uploaded, picture would still be retrieved as ImageFieldFile.  The following line checks the variable type of `picture` to determine whether the cleaning should proceed.
    if type(picture) != ImageFieldFile:
        image_field = self.cleaned_data.get('photo')
        image_file = BytesIO(image_field.read())
        image = Image.open(image_file)
        image = ImageOps.fit(image, (512,512,), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image_file = BytesIO()
        image.save(image_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)
        image_field.file = image_file
        #if picture._size > 2*1024*1024:
            #raise ValidationError("Image file too large.  Max size is 2MB.")
    return picture
```

---

```
class OwnerListingPhoto(models.Model):

    listing = models.ForeignKey(OwnerListing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_listing_photo')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=owner_listing_folder_name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that new versions of Django default to using `MemoryFileUploadHandler`, which doesn't create a temporary file, and therefore there is no file "name." [See related Django ticket.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28402)

You'll probably have to modify your code a bit to make this work, but you can at least start getting the name property by setting:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```

In your settings.py file.

You may find the code I've used to solve almost the exact same issue as helpful.

```
def clean_logo_file(self):
    logo_file_field = self.cleaned_data.get('logo_file')
    if logo_file_field:
        try:
            logo_file = logo_file_field.file
            with Image.open(logo_file_field.file.name) as image:
                image.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                image.save(logo_file, format=image.format)
                logo_file_field.file = logo_file
                return logo_file_field
        except IOError:
            logger.exception("Error during image resize.")
```

Additional information on [upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually ended up working around this issue by modifying the photo after it has been saved.

Answer (score 0):

- If file is **bigger** than **2.5mb** (2621440 bytes) - Django will
  use `TemporaryFileUploadHandler`.
- Otherwise Django will use `MemoryFileUploadHandler`.

You can change `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size)) in `settings.py`
Or change `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-handlers)) as **Nostalg.io** mentioned above.
My example with **Django Rest Framework** `serializers`:

**Broken code:**

```
# models.py
class ImageModel(Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=False, blank=False)

# serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ImageModel
        fields = ["id", "image"]
        read_only_fields = ["id"]

    def validate_image(self, user_img):
        img = Image.open(user_img)
        ...  # process image here
        img_io = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(img_io, format='JPEG', quality=100)
        filename = "%s.jpg" % user_img.name.split('.')[0]

        user_img.name = "%s.jpg" % user_img.name.split('.')[0]
        user_img.file = img_io  # BAD IDEA!!!
        # This overrides django's tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper() with _io.BytesIO() !!!
        ...
        return user_img  # if picture bigger than 2.5mb -> gives an error!
```

**Fixed code:**

```
#settings.py
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]

# serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ImageModel
        fields = ["id", "image"]
        read_only_fields = ["id"]

    def validate_image(self, user_img):
        img = Image.open(user_img)

        ...  # process image here

        # override old TemporaryFile image with edited image
        path_to_tmp = user_img.file.name
        new_filename = "%s.jpeg" % user_img.name.split('.')[0]

        # set new image name
        img.save(path_to_tmp, format='JPEG', quality=100)
        user_img.name = new_filename
        ...
        return user_img  # no errors more :)
```

It might be more rational to process image by rewriting `save()` method in `models.py`, but I convert images in `serializers.py` because of handly `ValidationError()` :)